# How can I find and clean a substring within a string using Perl?

Tags: html, perl

I have some HTML file that i need to edit.
I need to find some values in file and cleaning it form.

For example i have html file:

```
    .
    .
    Diagnostics
      align="right"
      align="right"
      align="right"
      align="right"
      align="right"
      align="right"
      align="right"

    Configuration
      align="right"
      align="right"
      align="right"
      align="right"
      align="right"
      align="right"
      align="right"
    .
    .
```

I need to find and clean

```
    Diagnostics
      align="right"
      align="right"
      align="right"
      align="right"
      align="right"
      align="right"
      align="right"
```

from my HTML file.

What a simple and very fast way to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: If you meant for your html tags to be visible, you need to use the Markdown formatting to set the text as a code field.

Answer (score 2):

Look at a module, such as [`HTML::TreeBuilder`](http://search.cpan.org/~cjm/HTML-Tree-5.03/lib/HTML/TreeBuilder.pm), for parsing HTML in Perl.  It is not a very simple task, but the linked documentation has some examples.  I suggest you try that and ask a specific question if you have trouble.

Another approach is using [regular expressions](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html).  This is generally not recommended for parsing HTML--it is impossible to reliably parse arbitrary HTML with regular expressions.  *However*, if you just want to quickly remove one kind of thing from files that have a predictable format, it can be a good choice.  Just make sure that your problem really is as simple as you think it is before going down this route.